# Pass Cell value to DB2 Connection String

Tags: vba, excel, db2

I am relatively new in VBA.

My requirement is to pass UID and PSW in DB2 connection string from the sheet cells. This is the working connection string:

```
objMyConn.Open "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=DBName;Hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=123;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=" & "XYZ" & ";Pwd=" & "Password"
```

I want to pass Uid and Pwd from cell A2 and B2 respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the passwords as variables and pass them:

```
Sub TestMe()

    With Worksheets(1)
        Dim pwd As String: pwd = .Range("B2")
        Dim uid As String: uid = .Range("A2")
    End With
    objMyConn.Open "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=DBName;" & _
        "Hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=123;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=" & uid & ";Pwd=" & pwd

End Sub
```

Thus, before passing the parameters some checks could be carried out:

```
If IsError(pwd) Then
If Len(pwd) < 6 Then
```

Comment: For some reason, I am getting invalid credential error, even though the cells contain correct details.